# CRON job for codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, installation, cron

I am using codeigniter. I want to know how to set up a cron job to check a table for expiring users and insert data in to another table with the list of expiring users. How to do that.

When i tried to write a script with controller and model to insert the table:

> **Fatal error**:  Class 'Controller' not found in **/home/content/html/test/live/application/controllers/cron.php** on line **2**

Comment: So... the question is the cron part or the codeigniter part?

Comment: Why do you need to insert data from one table to another?

Comment: CRON? Like, is it an acronym? Or just to make it clear that we're not talking about your regular, everyday jobs?

Answer (score 4):

You can find some more information on making CodeIgniter CLI-accessible here:
http://phpstarter.net/2008/12/run-codeigniter-from-the-command-line-ssh/

Next step is just using crontab -e to set up the cronjob.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be what you're looking for, but it works just fine for me:

Create your CRON job logic as a 'normal' controller function.

Then, in your standard, non-CI, PHP cronjob file just load the URL via

```
file_get_contents('http:example.com/cronjob/');
```

This will treat the URL as being hit just as by any other user and the entire CI framework will be at your disposal.

Comment: ...which is fine, if you want your cron job's logic exposed to the network, not so great otherwise.  CI provides a mechanism for executing via the CL for a reason.

Comment: How exactly does that "expose the logic"? It merely allows others to call the same procedure. If that's an issue you can add a signature to the request or have it only call from its own IP.

Comment: Right - it allows the Internet to execute your logic.  Is that desireable for what's supposed to be a cron-driven process?  Ever?  No.  Yes you can do IP filterting, etc. but in the end you're just band-aiding what is the *wrong approach* from the start.  Use the tools CodeIgniter gives you.  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html

Comment: Executing and exposing are not the same. I see no issue facilitating a http call as a trigger, especially not on a web application. What exactly is your concern here?

Comment: Do you want my bot triggering your "supposed-to-be-a-cron-job" inner workings thousands of times per hour?  Of course not, so you set up things like IP filters, etc.  Again - to lock down the visibility of functionality that shouldn't have been exposed in the first place.

Comment: See 1st line of my answers: "it works just fine for me". I've set up jobs with IP lockdown like this for years. Never had a problem.

Comment: The fact that *it works* doesn't mean it's the right way to go about it.  Do you use tables for HTML page layouts?  Do you drive backwards to the mall?  Do you communicate with your neighbor using carrier pigeons?  The point is, there's a right way (using the tools that CI provides for the task) vs. all of the other ways.  Other ways may work, but they're not the best way...as evidenced by the need to jump through extra hoops by doing things like IP whitelisting, etc.  Best of luck!

Comment: Your comment/attitude is childish and inappropriate.

Comment: I agree with Rid Iculous, this can be a good solution for some. A bot can target ANY part of your application... in which case you blacklist their IP at the server level. As long as your Cron doesn't expose sensitive information, I technically don't see any problem with this. CLI is the "right" way to do it, but this way works as well. Choose based on the requirements of your specific application.

Comment: Although, it should be file_get_contents(); Im guessing that's a typo above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking on how to create cron job, then have a look at this:

http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

But if you *mean* how to put expired users into another table, then you should show your table structure.

Answer (score -2):

My hosting site is godaddy which give the option to create a cron. All we need to do is write a plainphp page to do the job, with sql connection and all stuff and just upload to the godaddy server and create the cron. Thats it. Job is easier.