# How to add a cron job in codeigniter controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

How to delete the jobs automatically while after one month using a cron in PHP

```
public function deletejobs()
    {
        $qry="select *from jobs where job_posting_date <unix_timestamp(now()-interval 31 day)";
        $res=$this->db->query($qry)->result_array();
        foreach($res as $result){
            $this->db->where('jobid',$result['jobid'])->update('jobs',array('job_status'=>expired));
        }
        //exit;
        redirect(base_url());


        $this->template->write_view('content', 'Jobs/job_center',$data);
        $this->template->render();
    }
```

Comment: You better search before posting question. you can find it here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236423/cron-job-for-codeigniter)

Comment: I'm afraid to ask what a corn job is...

Comment: @RockyTriton: I'm amaized you didn't make a pun.