# How To Create CronJob in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, cron

How To Create CronJob in codeigniter?

I am basically insert values to a table of database at 6pm everyday through cronjob
So how can i do that. Help me!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236423/cron-job-for-codeigniter

Comment: http://rcadhikari.blogspot.in/2012/05/creating-cron-jobs-in-codeigniter-ci.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a regular controller that performs the actions you wish the be executed, and then set up the cronjob in for example cPanel like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/sitefolder/public_html/index.php/controller/function
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your CRON job logic as a 'normal' CI controller function.

Then, in your standard, non-CI, PHP cronjob file just load the URL of the controller via

```
get_get_contents('http:example.com/cronjob/');
```

This will treat the URL as being hit just as by any other user and the entire CI framework is  at your disposal in the CI controller.