# I want to call cron from codeigniter 3 version

Tags: php

We are working on automatic mail now.
I am trying to implement automatic mail using cron.
How do I call cron from the controller??

```
exec("0 * * *, php installation path php, public_html/index.php SendMail autoMail")
```

I called it because I was told to call it like this, but it doesn't work.

I want to control automatic mail by creating, modifying, and deleting cron in the controller.

Comment: Not sure where you were told to call `cron` like that, but please don't. Instead make use of `cron` commands on the server itself (or cPanel, if you're using shared hosting).

Comment: `exec()` is for executing shell commands. That needs to be put in the user's crontab with the `crontab` command. Also, you have an extra `,` and you're missing one of the schedule fields.

Comment: exec("0 0 * * * /php path/php -q /codeigniterdirectory/index.php controllerName methodName");
I got the answer that I can call it from the controller like this.

Comment: Wherever you got that answer, it is wrong.  That is not a command, it is the format of a crontab file, which is something like a config file for running things at specific times.  `cron` is a server/OS utility, not something you "run" or call from CI.  You can set up `cron` to run one of your CI CLI processes though, and there are many examples of how to do that here on SO, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269566/how-to-set-cron-job-url-for-codeigniter; here's info about how to create a cronjob https://stackoverflow.com/a/878647/6089612

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set cron job url for codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269566/how-to-set-cron-job-url-for-codeigniter)

Comment: The cron must be created, modified, and deleted in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below code:

Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
class Cronjob extends CI_Controller {
static $model     = array();
static $helper    = array();
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
public function sendMail()
{
$msg = "test";
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
// send email
mail("youemail@gmail.com","yoursubject",$msg);
}}
```

**AND Then Search cronjob in cpanel then select job and write in command**

/usr/local/bin/php /Home Directory/public_html/index.php controllerName/funcionName

**EXAMPLE:**
/usr/local/bin/php /home3/faizuldev/public_html/index.php cronjob/sendMail

click :
[show screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4CcC.png)

Comment: The cron must be created, modified, and deleted in the controller.

Comment: you can find it here how it work in codeigniter [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236423/cron-job-for-codeigniter)